# ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 + Bootstrap datepicker + Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have already added ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 to my Meteor Project.

how can I add a Bootstrap datepicker field inside ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 ?

Comment: Are you using any Date-picker library? As far as I know you should include a text field in the form and have to initialise the date picker on that text field, after the form is rendered.

Comment: yes i meant the same, the date-picker library.